# How to making dynamic URLs for menus in Wordpress?

Tags: menus, urls

My Site Address (URL) is http://something.ddns.net/PS. I have a header Custom Links menu URL like this "/#services". This takes me to a location on the current page but I want it to take me to the location on a root page. Is there a variable I can use that represents Site Address (URL) or WordPress Address (URL), e.g. "[site_url]/#services"?

I need this because I want to be able to change my site's URL without going through all the menus and changing the URL. I want menus to reflect the site root from the settings of the Wordpress.

Related question: 
When I click the link for the first time it does not jump to #services on the page, why do I need to click on it twice in the row?

Edited:
Why would anyone want links to be relative to the root and not to the Site Address (URL)?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Custom Link URL exactly as written in your example, it should work as expected. "/" at the beginning already means "site root", and it should work on single (first) click. Maybe you have some menu related plugin installed, or your theme changes menu URLs in some way. Or there is client side javascript involved.

What URL do you see in browser status bar (lower left corner) when you hover over custom menu link? It should be `[site_root]/#services`.

**UPDATE**:

When WordPress is installed in subdirectory `/#services` will link to incorrect page. There is no way to add `[site_root]` prefix in menu URLs, so you either use have to use real URL `/PS/#services` (and will have to change them all after changing site root) or you can add filter to automatically prefix all menu items starting with `/`. Just keep in mind, that in case you need to add link to **real** site root, you must use full URL `http://something.ddns.net/` instead of `/`.

```
function my_nav_menu_link_attributes( $atts ) {
    if ( '/' == substr( $atts['href'], 0, 1 ) ) {
        $atts['href'] = site_url() . $atts['href'];
    }
    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'my_nav_menu_link_attributes', 20 );
```

Comment: My site URL is http://something.ddns.net/PS, that is why it does not work and why I asked is there a variable that represents my WordPress Address (URL) or Site Address (URL).

Comment: @HrvojeBatrnek see my updated answer.

Comment: Well, in this function my_nav_menu_link_attributes I could add support for [site_url] placeholder. e.g. [site_url]/#services

Comment: It does not work. Links won't change, It's like the function is not even being called. Why?

Comment: I have other filters and they do work, so I know where to put the code, but this one does not work.

Comment: To check whether function is called you may unconditionally change `$atts['href']` to something completely different and see whether it changes your links.

Comment: I did that, and it does not work.

Comment: Most likely you have some other filter changing you nave menu links or your theme uses own function to generate links.